custom numbering of tasks in the frame
I want to make some kind of variant of the exam on A4 sheet. So I have a question, how to make custom numbering of assignments like on this photo? If it is possible, it would be desirable that this numbering could be called by a custom command. I need the easiest way possible


You can simply override the \questionlabel as follows:
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\fbox{\thequestion}}

Here is a complete example:
\documentclass{exam}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\fbox{\thequestion}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question When in doubt, should one provide a minimal working example?
\question When in doubt, should one provide some minimal working example?
\end{questions}

\end{document}

If you want, you can also control the width of the box with following override instead:
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\framebox[1cm]{\thequestion}}


Uh, hold on. I need the text to be left-aligned while moving the line, but not exceeding the task number. Here is an example. I'm sorry it's in Russian.

Try \question First line is in Russian\\ $\log_7 (1-x) = \log_7 5$. or \question First line is in Russian\\[0.5\baselineskip] $\log_7 (1-x) = \log_7 5$.

Unfortunately neither of these worked out the way I wanted, but I don't want to bother you anymore. Thanks for the numbering anyway.

You are welcome. Maybe you can post a separate question, possibly with an MWE.
